# Systems of imprimitivity for irreducible subgroup of GU(n,q)

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, unitary-representations

My question is similar to [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/290354/systems-of-imprimitivity-for-unitary-representations-reference-request) but about finite field case.

So, the set up is the following:

Let $G$ be $GU_n(q)$ acting on unitary space $(V, {\bf f})$, where $V=\mathbb{F}_{q^2}^n$ and ${\bf f}:V \times V \to \mathbb{F}_{q^2}$ is non-degenerate unitary form. Let $H \le G$ be irreducible and imprimitive with a system of imprimitivity:
$$V=V_1 \oplus \ldots \oplus V_k.$$

Now, since $H$ is irreducible, all $V_i$-s  are either non-degenerate or totally isotropic. Let us, for simplicity, stick with the first option, so assume that all $V_i$-s  are non-degenerate subspaces of $V.$

My question is: is it true that ${\bf f}(V_i,V_j)=0$ for $i \ne j$?

An additional question is: If the statement in the first question is false, can I find another imprimitivity system of $H$ for which it is true?

The proof in [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/290354/systems-of-imprimitivity-for-unitary-representations-reference-request) works only for algebraically closed fields. In particular, if $H$ is absolutely irreducible, then the answer is yes.

Comment: I don't know the answer.  The answer to the corresponding question for the symplectic groups with $V_1$ a totally isotropic subspace is no. An example is ${\rm Sp}(6,13)$, which has an imprimitive subgroup $H \cong {\rm SL}(2,5)$ which acts imprimitively on six 1-dimensional subspaces, but does not preserve a symplectic system of imprimitivity.